# How to get group-by and get most frequent words and bigrams for each group pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently dealing with a dataframe like this:

```
 words:                               other:   category:    
 hello, jim, you, you , jim            val1      movie
 it, seems, bye, limb, pat, paddy      val2      movie
 how, are, you, are , kim              val1      television
 ......
 ......
```

I am trying to calculate the top 10 most frequently occurring words, and bigrams for each of the categories in the 'category' column. Although, I want to calculate the most common bigrams before grouping them into the respective category.

My problem is that if I group by category and then get the top10 most frequently occurring bigrams, the words from the first row will be merged with the second row.

The bigrams should be as follows:

```
 (hello, jim), (jim, you), (you, you), (you, jim)
 (it, seems), (seems,bye), (bye, limb), (limb, pat), (pat, paddy)
 (how, are), (are, you), (you, are), (are, kim)
```

Whereas if I group before getting the bigrams, the bigrams would be:

```
 (hello, jim), (jim, you), (you, you), (you, jim), (jim, it), (it, seems), (seems,bye), (bye, limb), (limb, pat), (pat, paddy)
 (how, are), (are, you), (you, are), (are, kim)
```

What is the best way to do this using pandas?

Apologies if my question is unnecessarily complicated, I just wanted to include all details. Please let me know any questions.

Comment: How are you getting the bigrams currently?

Comment: Can you please post your bigram function again?

Answer (score 1):

Example data frame:

```
                                   words other    category
0             hello, jim, you, you , jim  val1       movie
1  it, seems, bye, limb, pat, hello, jim  val2       movie
2               how, are, you, are , kim  val1  television
```

Here is a method to compute bigrams using Pandas and `.iterrows()`:

```
bigrams = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    lst = row['words'].split(',')
    bigrams.append([(lst[x].strip(), lst[x+1].strip()) for x in range(len(lst)-1)])

print(bigrams)
```

```
[[('hello', 'jim'), ('jim', 'you'), ('you', 'you'), ('you', 'jim')], 
[('it', 'seems'), ('seems', 'bye'), ('bye', 'limb'), ('limb', 'pat'), ('pat', 'hello'), ('hello', 'jim')], 
[('how', 'are'), ('are', 'you'), ('you', 'are'), ('are', 'kim')]]
```

Here is a more efficient method using Pandas and `.apply`:

```
def bigram(row):
    lst = row['words'].split(', ')
    return [(lst[x].strip(), lst[x+1].strip()) for x in range(len(lst)-1)]

bigrams = df.apply(lambda row: bigram(row), axis=1)

print(bigrams.tolist())
```

```
[[('hello', 'jim'), ('jim', 'you'), ('you', 'you'), ('you', 'jim')], 
[('it', 'seems'), ('seems', 'bye'), ('bye', 'limb'), ('limb', 'pat'), ('pat', 'hello'), ('hello', 'jim')], 
[('how', 'are'), ('are', 'you'), ('you', 'are'), ('are', 'kim')]]
```

You can then group the data by category and find the top 10 most common bigrams. Here is an example of finding the most frequent bigrams by category:

```
df['bigrams'] = bigrams
df2 = df.groupby('category').agg({'bigrams': 'sum'})

# Compute the most frequent bigrams by category
from collections import Counter
df3 = df2.bigrams.apply(lambda row: Counter(row)).to_frame()
```

Ordered dictionary of bigram frequency by category:

```
print(df3)

                                                      bigrams
category                                                     
movie       {('hello', 'jim'): 2, ('jim', 'you'): 1, ('you...
television  {('how', 'are'): 1, ('are', 'you'): 1, ('you',...
```

```
# Filter to just the top 3 most frequent bigrams (or 10 if you have enough data)
df3.bigrams.apply(lambda row: list(row)[0:3])
```

```
category
movie         [(hello, jim), (jim, you), (you, you)]
television      [(how, are), (are, you), (you, are)]
Name: bigrams, dtype: object
```

Comment: This seems to be taking a significant time to run over a large dataframe. Is there anyway to improve the efficiency of your solution? Also this solution only prints the bigrams, how do I format this to group for each category? Thanks!

Comment: There probably is, depending on how you compute the bigrams. Does every row in the ``'words:'`` column have the exact same number of elements?

Comment: No they have different numbers of words.

Comment: Okay. If they had the same number of elements, I could recommend a more efficient method.

Comment: @jackiegirl89 I have added a more efficient method using ``apply``.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this only solves half of the problem. The main problem I have is trying to then get the top10 bigrams for each category.

Comment: @jackiegirl89 I have updated the answer to include this functionality. Please let me know if this addresses your question.

Comment: Hey @Nathaniel, I'm struggling and trying to understand what does "row" actually do in the .apply method to create Bigram? Can you help me understand please?